# Getting sibling using xPath

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

I am currently working on a .net C# solution that returns 2 sibling nodes. Using Xpath 1.0

A small example of my xml doc is this:

```
<PLAY>
 <SCENE>
  <SPEAKER>
  </SPEAKER>
  <LINE>
  </LINE>
  </SCENE>
</PLAY>
```

I am using the following code to get the line and the speaker but i dont know why i get the entire xml doc being passed in instead of just the sibling (speaker)

I have :

```
List speakers = new List();

XmlDocument myDoc = new XmlDocument();
myDoc.Load(textXMLFile.Text.ToString());
// Clear the text box...
textResults.Text = "";

// ADD THIS...
XPathNavigator theNav = myDoc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNavigator theNav2 = myDoc.CreateNavigator();

//XmlNodeList theNodes =
//    myDoc.SelectNodes(textXPath.Text.ToString());

textXPath.Text = "//SPEECH/LINE";
string val = "//SPEECH/SPEAKER";
XPathNodeIterator theNodes = theNav.Select(textXPath.Text.ToString());
XPathNodeIterator theNodes2 = theNav2.Select(val);

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

while (theNodes.MoveNext())
{
    if (theNodes.Current.InnerXml.ToString() == "Upon my sword.")
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        speakers.Add(theNodes2.Current.InnerXml.ToString());
        speakers.Add(theNodes2.Current.InnerXml.ToString());
    }
}
for (int i =0; i < speakers.Count; ++i)
{
    output.Append (speakers[i]+" ");
}
MessageBox.Show(""+output);
```

`theNodes.Current.InnerXml.ToString()` works fine for returning the line but `theNodes2.Current.InnerXml.ToString()` seems to return the entire XML instead of the speaker.

Any comments or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Should one of those `speakers.Add` lines be `speakers.Add(theNodes.Current.InnerXml.ToString());`? Right now both of them are using `theNodes2`.

Comment: What level is <Speech/> at in the Xml ?

Comment: I actually figure it out .. i needed to loop theNodes2 also in my while loop. Thanks all. I would post as an answer but i dont have enough rep to answer my own question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After staring at this for awhile i totally missed that i needed to move theNodes2 also in the while loop like so

`while(theNodes2.MoveNext())`

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

//SPEECH/LINE is not going to find anything in a document where the elements are named "play", "scene", "speaker", and "line". Please try to be more careful in formulating your questions. Downvoting.

Comment: Im sorry. I was just creating a small xml document quickly since the real thing is massive. It didnt seem to be a problem since for the most part people knew what i was talking about. But I guess i'll accept your downvote as constructive criticism -- although I really could use the points so I can mark my answer as correct faster.